# send_nsca not working on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu microinstance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, nagios

After installing Nagios Core, nsca is installed following the next steps:

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/download/contrib/documentation/misc/NSCA_Setup.pdf

When testing send_nsca from localhost

```
./send_nsca localhost -c ../sample-config/send_nsca.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/test_nsca
```

where test_nsca is a text file containing:

```
localhost TestMessage 0 This is a test message.
```

the response is: 
0 data packet(s) sent to host successfully.

And syslog shows:

```
Jul 21 16:10:47 ip-172-31-46-129 nsca[19462]: Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 738
Jul 21 16:10:47 ip-172-31-46-129 nsca[19462]: Handling the connection...
Jul 21 16:10:47 ip-172-31-46-129 nsca[19462]: End of connection...
```

It does not use port 5667, instead it uses a different port each time.
I have a security group with all ports opened (TCP and UDP) from any host.

Any idea?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, it was do to the elements in test_nsca file where separated by spaces instead of tabulator.